# Read file and count duplicate ports in X column

Tags: bash, file

I have the following text file:

output.log

Estructure of file text:

5896; 192.168.1.1 **443** 186.56.21.30 Rule: 45;
4587; 192.168.1.1 **80**  196.46.65.12 Rule: 25;
7815; 192.168.2.1 **443** 185.45.65.23 Rule: 10;
5578; 192.168.3.5 **535** 165.98.45.45 Rule: 5;
4587; 192.168.1.1 **80**  196.46.65.12 Rule: 25;

**I would like to know how many times X port of column 3 is repeated without knowing its value or typing it in the script.**

At the moment I am testing this code, just to understand the logic, but I really find how to do it right.

```
file="output.log"
cat $file  | awk {'print $1, $2, $3, $4, $27, $5, $6'} | tr -d ';' | tr -d ':' | grep "Rule" | while read src_port src_ip dst_port dst_ip rule num_rule;
do  
    uniq_dst_port=$(cat $file | awk {'print $3'} | tr -d ';' | tr -d ':' | sort | uniq)

    for u_dst_port in $uniq_dst_port;
    do
        #echo "FIRST BUCLE: $dst_port SECOND_BUCLE: $u_dst_port"
        #sleep 1
        if [[ $dst_port == $u_dst_port ]]; then
            #echo "IS EQUAL...."
            n=$((n+1))
        fi
    done
    if [[ $dst_port == $dst_port ]]; then
        echo "The Port: $dst_port  repeat $n Time"
    else
        echo "" >> /dev/null
    fi
done
```

**REAL OUTPUT:**

The Port: 443  repeat 1 Time
The Port: 443  repeat 2 Time
The Port: 80  repeat 3 Time
The Port: 53  repeat 4 Time
The Port: 53  repeat 5 Time
The Port: 80  repeat 6 Time
The Port: 993  repeat 7 Time
The Port: 443  repeat 8 Time

**OUTPUT THAT I LIKE IN FUTURE:**

The Port 443 repeat 2 Time in the Rule 45, 10.
The Port 80 repeat 2 Time in the Rule 25.
The Port 535 repeat 1 Time in the Rule 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r _ _ port _ _ rule; do
    rules[port]+=${rule%;}$'\n'
done

for port in "${!rules[@]}"; do
    list=${rules[port]}
    n=${list//[^$'\n']}
    printf -v list "%s, " $(sort -nu <<< "$list")
    printf "The port %d repeat %d times for rules %s.\n" $port ${#n} "${list%??}"
done
```

`./script < output.log`
prints out

```
The port 80 repeat 2 times for rules 25.
The port 443 repeat 2 times for rules 10, 45.
The port 535 repeat 1 times for rules 5.
```

Comment: What mean %d %d %s in the printf last line?? Where are investigate more for this topic with examples? @M. Nejat Aydin thanks

Comment: @LestherMartinReyesEspinoza In `printf`, `%d` means the corresponding argument will be printed as a decimal integer, and as a string for `%s`. Look for `printf` in [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html). Also related to (but different from) bash's printf: read the manual page of `printf(3)`: `man 3 printf`, or [fprintf](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1). Read the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to understand `${#n}` and `${list%??}`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approximation to get the desired output might be

```
$ more output.log
5896; 192.168.1.1 443 186.56.21.30 Rule: 45;
4587; 192.168.1.1 80 196.46.65.12 Rule: 25;
7815; 192.168.2.1 443 185.45.65.23 Rule: 10;
5578; 192.168.3.5 535 165.98.45.45 Rule: 5;
4587; 192.168.1.1 80 196.46.65.12 Rule: 25;
```

Then, my test.sh script to process it

```
$ more test.sh 

# determine unique ports

uniq_dst_port=$(cat output.log | awk {'print $3'} | tr -d ';' | tr -d ':' | sort | uniq)

# list of ports with repetitions

repe_dst_port=$(cat output.log  | awk {'print $3'} | tr -d ';' | tr -d ':')

# for each one how many entries

if [[ -f tmpfile.txt ]] ; then rm -f tmpfile.txt 2>&1 ; fi

# now use the rules to add them to the expression

for i in $uniq_dst_port
do
        repetitions=$(cat output.log | awk {'print $3'} | tr -d ';' | tr -d ':' | egrep "$i" | wc -l)
        #echo "The port $i repeat $repetitions times"
        rules_per_port=$(cat output.log | egrep "$i" | sort | uniq | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\;/\,/')
        for h in $rules_per_port
        do
                varrules=$(cat output.log  | egrep "$i" | sort | uniq | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\;/\,/' | awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }')
                varrules=$(echo $varrules | sed 's/.$//')
                # control varrules already applied
                echo "The port $i repeat $repetitions times for rules $varrules" >> tmpfile.txt
        done
done

cat tmpfile.txt | sort | uniq
```

Then, a run example

```
$ more output.log
5896; 192.168.1.1 443 186.56.21.30 Rule: 45;
4587; 192.168.1.1 80 196.46.65.12 Rule: 25;
7815; 192.168.2.1 443 185.45.65.23 Rule: 10;
5578; 192.168.3.5 535 165.98.45.45 Rule: 5;
4587; 192.168.1.1 80 196.46.65.12 Rule: 25;
$ ./test.sh
The port 443 repeat 2 times for rules 45, 10
The port 535 repeat 1 times for rules 5
The port 80 repeat 2 times for rules 25
```

Basically the main issue was building the rules as an array associated when you have to convert all rows to one column separated by comma. This code works in any bash version.

As last step I build a temp file to sort and apply uniq to the contents, thereby avoiding duplicates. I also applied to the array build in order to avoid duplicate rules for the same port.

Comment: can you edit your question and provide the content of the input file ? In my case I used the example you provided in your question.

Comment: i the output of tmpfile.txt i am see that the ultimate line repeat 5 time with this:

The port **80** repeat 2 times for rules 25, 25, 5, 45, 10

Why?

Comment: The input file is the same on my post.

Comment: Mmmm the error is that in my input file the last caracter in each line is a space....

Comment: if you have blank spaces at the end, use this sed 's/ *$//g'`

Comment: Thanks @Roberto Hernandez

Comment: Hi @LestherMartinReyesEspinoza , why did you revoke the accept  in the answer ?? or at least if you dod that, upvote the answer that you are grateful for the help provided.

Comment: You are reading the entire file (output.log) and calling external commands too many times. This is an overkill. The job could be done in one pass as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @LxerLx, I am not saying that  The accepted answer is better, for sure, but does not imply to be grateful when someone is answering all the questions in the comments and working in helping to solve the issue. I believe that is also worth it

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{ print $3 }' output.log | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print "The Port " $2 " repeat " $1 "2 Time." }'
```

The output is

```
The Port 443 repeat 22 Time.
The Port 535 repeat 12 Time.
The Port 80 repeat 22 Time.
```

Comment: Thank dear,

Yes, this is great, but I would like to keep the line number in case I want to print below the sources where the match was found. That is why I want to do it with loops, that is, I want to know how to deal with the handling of loops in this case.